# Include a *.d.ts file (and the corresponding JS) in a TypeScript project using PHPStorm

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to dive into TypeScript (because to me it looks very promising) and therefore I want to rewrite a little JS project of my own.

So I started to create some classes (each class in a seperate file), but I'm a little bit confused about those *.d.ts files.

How do I exactly work with them? Do I need to reference them in the .ts files? Because PHPStorm seems to index the *.d.ts file anyway.

I'm using grunt-ts (https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts) to compile the project down to JavaScript, seems that this one needs the reference files.

But when I'm referencing it like so in the first line:

```
///<reference path="../../../lib/typed/jquery.d.ts">
```

The compiler says:

```
....Model.ts(37, 20): error TS1084: Invalid reference directive syntax.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That needs to be a self closing tag :

```
///<reference path="../../../lib/typed/jquery.d.ts" />
```

Notice `/>` at the end